# Two-way communication between esp32s

Tags: i2c, serial, communication, digital-communications

I am planning a circuit that requires two-way communication between one esp32 and 3 others. I want to use a master/slave architecture as shown here:
[image: Planned Architecture]They need to be able to communicated **via hardware**, not wirelessly!
Is this possible using the following circuit?
[image: 1]
(in this circuit, the CLK pins are serial clock pins and the SD pins are serial data pins, i plan to use i2c (which may also need the arduinos to have a common ground...))

Any solutions/ideas are appreciated

Comment: What are the functions of these pins? Which protocol are you planning to use? Please edit the question.

Comment: my apologies @LongPham, question updated

Comment: How long are the wires?

Comment: The wires are 20cm (~ 8”)